# Not able to pass default values to parameters in stored procedure Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "abc"(  i_sample_size  FLOAT DEFAULT 1.0)
```

Error

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redshift PL/pgSQL is based on old PostgreSQL (version 8.0) with some backports (procedures). The default arguments was implemented in PostgreSQL 8.4, and it looks like are not supported in Redshift still.